# Use domain at home

Tags: google, domains, web-hosting

I bought a domain name when I join GSuite.

Now I want to cancel my GSuite account.

Nevertheless I have my domain and I paid for it till the end of the year.

So my question is, with whom I must contact just to keep my domain name active and renew it at the end of the year.

Concerning the hosting, I will try to redirect the domain name to my computer at home. Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also contact 24/7 Google support regarding the same
https://gsuite.google.co.in/intl/en_in/support/

**Option 1:**
Manage domain registration renewals

https://support.google.com/a/answer/4377734?hl=en

**Option 2:**
Transfer your domain to another host

https://support.google.com/a/answer/171715?hl=en

**Concerning the hosting, I will try to redirect the domain name to my computer at home. Is this possible?**

Yes, If you have running server at home then it's possible otherwise you can also buy some hosting, There are some free hosting option available in the market like 000webhost.

Comment: A caveat is that some ISPs do not allow web site hosting. He needs to ask his ISP about that.